# How can i fix errors E0003,C1014 that occurred when i try to include some header files simultaneously?

Tags: c, list, header, include, guard

Having said that I've tried to solve the problem surfing the net and I've found some questions very similar to my problem, but despite this i didn't come to any solution.
I would like if anynone could help me about the problem, explaining what doesn't work instead of redirect me to another blog.

Here the code:

1)file: list.h

```
#include "list.c"
#include "element.h"


typedef struct list_element {
    element value;
    struct list_element* next;
} item;
typedef item* list;


list emptyList(void);
boolean empty(list);
element head(list);
list tail(list);
list cons(element, list);
.......
```

2. file list.c

```
    #include "list.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    list emptyList(void) {
        return NULL;
    }

    boolean empty(list l) {
        if (l == NULL)
            return true; 
        else
            return false;
    }

    list tail(list l) {
        if (empty(l))
            return NULL;
        else
            return l->next;
    }
....
```

3)file element.h

```
#include "element.c"

#ifndef ELEMENT_H
#define ELEMENT_H

typedef int element;
typedef enum { false, true } boolean;

boolean isLess(element, element);
boolean isEqual(element, element);
element getElement(void);
void printElement(element);
```

4. file element.c

```
#include "element.h"
#include <stdio.h>

boolean isEqual(element e1, element e2) {
    return (e1 == e2); 
}

boolean isLess(element e1, element e2) {
    return (e1 < e2);
}

element getElement() {
    element el;
    scanf(" %d", &el);
    return el;
}

void printElement(element el) {
    printf(" % d", el);
}
```

then the compiler gave me error code:

```
 E0003(file #include /../../../../../../element.h includes itself)
```

and error

````
code C1014 (too many file of inclusion, depth=1024) for file list.c and element.c```
So I've tried to use the guards (surely in the wrong way) and the error list was almost the same.
I would be grateful if someone could help me out
thank you for the attention.
````

Comment: Never include **`.c`** files

Comment: Do not ever include `.c` files. (well, until you start considering yourself a programmer of a somewhat advanced level fully aware of the consequences)

Comment: @EugeneSh. how can i use functions of list.c and element.c if i don't include them in their  header.h

Comment: @ric - you do not use them in the .h file. Do not add any code or data to the .h file

Comment: @0___________
 yes certainly, but what I'm trying to say is that when I use a certain function of (for example) list.c in the main ,  if I cut off #include list.c in the file .h how is possible that I can use all the functions of list.c?

Comment: There is a very simple way to think about `#include`. It is simply taking the file and pasting its content. If you think about it this way, you will avoid any confusion like this. So you can think of your project as being consisting of `.c` files only with the headers pasted in.

Answer (score 1):

In your program you include .h file, which includes .h file, which includes the .c file ...... until you reach the compiler include depth level which is 1024 in your case.

Remove

```
#include "element.c"
```

and remove

```
#include "list.c"
```

**`*.h`** files (header files) should not contain any data or function definitions. Those files should only have types and extern data declarations, macrodefinition, function prototypes and (when you are more advanced) `static inline` functions definitions

Comment: if i remove them how can the linker find list.c and element.c?

Comment: @ric linker does not care about your .h files You need to tell the linker which object files you want to link together. As for your level use Eclipse or other IDE which will do it for you automatically.  Do not push yourself beyond your knowledge level at the moment.